# Deploy Azure Face API for IoT Edge

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api, azure-iot-edge

Is it possible to deploy Azure Face API trained model to IoT Edge like Custom Vision?

If it is, please answer me how to do that?

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Custom-vision-service-iot-edge-raspberry-pi

Comment: Yes, but this is for Custom Vision API. This is made with the customvision.ai website where you can easily export model. I need that for Face API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updating this topic...

Now you can download a Docker Image with the Face API for running it on-premises.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-how-to-install-containers#summary) you can find the documentation for testing this feature, that currently is in public preview.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-container-support#containers-in-azure-cognitive-services) you can see the list of all the Azure Cognitive Services that are available as Docker Containers.

**This new feature basically is targeting enterprises that:**

- Are not willing or able to load all their data into the cloud for processing or storage;
- Are subject to regulatory requirements on handling customer data;
- Have data that they aren’t comfortable sharing and processing in a cloud, regardless of security;
- Have weak bandwidth or disconnected environments with high latency and TPS issues.

Answer (score 0):

Model export is not a feature supported by the Face API.

Comment: A new [update](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/running-cognitive-service-containers/) was released in Nov 2018 allowing the usage of the Face API on the Edge...